# NodeJS - directory structure pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, architecture, structure

I'm new to web Development and NodeJS, and I'm refactoring our app (code and directories structure).

And I would like to have the opinion of more experienced developers about the file structure pattern I would like to use.

**An usual MVC app structure could look like this:**

```
/config
/server
    /controller (business logic)
    /models (contain all models)
    /routes (contain all routes)
    /middlewares (express middleware)
/views (server templates)
/app (contain JS client app)
/public (assets, ...)
/test
```

This structure allow us to group files by concern.

**But what if we use an app structure that group files by service - e.g:**

```
/config
/lib
   /middlewares (express middlewares)
   /services (utils modules, db modules, ...)
   /config
/views
/public
/app
/server
   /user
       /routes
       /logic
       /test
       /model
       /validation-schema
       /...
   /articles
       /routes
       /logic
       ...
```

Views, templating and client directories are the same like in the first structure. It's more about server API structure.

This allow us to have all file related to the user entity in the same directory. Including test, models, routes..

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to start a religious war @SimonBruneaud.  :).  Both versions are totally viable, many folks use either.  The second one is somewhat more modular, and in fact you could arguably develop and version each of the server sub folders as separate npm modules if you wanted.  the MEAN framework uses something similar, though they actually package everything (including client code and templates) along those lines.

Ultimately I think it's a matter of personal preference, and I suspect your question will be closed as Primarily Opinion before long.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ill keep it in mind.

Comment: Np.  I failed to point out the difficulty of the modular design, which I've found to be the inevitable interdependencies.  For example, your "articles" module almost inevitably needs to know about and import from your User module.  Not insurmountable, but it does mean things are never as cleanly separated as the initial file structure might suggest.

Comment: Yes that's why I don't know if the modular pattern can be used.
Our team is going to work on microservice architecture, and to do so, the modular structure allow us to easily manage pieces of code.